# FragmentActivity crashes because of a GoogleMap inside one of the fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a fragment activity as seen in my last question:

[App crashing when using fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083375/app-crashing-when-using-fragments/19083608)

It crushes because of a GoogleMap inside one of my fragments (MainActivity).

right now thats the code:

```
private GoogleMap map;

map = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager() .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I cant change GoogleMap. it causes other problems in my code as im using it.

What should I do?

Thanks for your assistance!

Ive tried to relocate that piece of code to `onCreateView`. Doesn't work either.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "crush".

Comment: Can you give more information, for example, where is this line in your code, in `onCreate`? Which type of error are you getting?

Comment: @CommonsWare I already know what caused it.. its the GoogleMap. a fragment within a fragment.

Comment: @betorcs this code, is inside a fragment. this fragment is used by a `FragmentActivity`. it crashes because one fragment cant be nested into another one. But it actually possiable. I just cant do that right - if I change `GoogleMap` it causes other errors...

Comment: I see. If you want You can add a fragment inside other using getChildFragmentManager() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager(). And the errors you are getting maybe because of GoogleMap lifecycle, make sure, you are getting it after onCreate.

Comment: @betorcs I still dont get it.: `Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment`

Comment: Have you inserted the map class (With package9 in the xml file?